# jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 + Photoswipe 1.0.11

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I am trying to implement the latest version of Photoswipe with the latest version of jQuery Mobile. I even use the already made examples included into Photoswipe download file and I am just updating jQuery & jQuery mobile to the latest versions. Immediately after doing that, the gallery does not work. Have anyone managed to make it work?

If it is impossible, any good alternative to it with works with the latest jQuery Mobile?

Best,

Comment: make sure you initialize the plugin on `pagecontainershow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep using Photoswipe. Your problem is version mismatch. Original developer stopped working on this framework few weeks ago and another developer overtook this project. But what is not known is that this second developer forked this project a long time ago and that there are 2 separate versions of this plugin.

Original one stopped working with jQuery Mobile ago. This second implementation currently holds version: 3.0.5. Unfortunately this version is no longer available. From my knowledge second developer is working on merging this two projects together.

Thankfully I have available version 3.0.4

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PFqVs/

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/photoswipe.css" />        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://thecodingwebsite.com/tutorials/photoswipe/klass.min.js"></script>            
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>            
        <script src="http://thecodingwebsite.com/tutorials/photoswipe/code.photoswipe.jquery-3.0.4.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
                <h1>Index page</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <ul class="gallery">           
                    <li><a href="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/full/001.jpg" rel="external"><img src="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/thumb/001.jpg" alt="Image 001" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/full/002.jpg" rel="external"><img src="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/thumb/002.jpg" alt="Image 002" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/full/003.jpg" rel="external"><img src="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/thumb/003.jpg" alt="Image 003" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/full/004.jpg" rel="external"><img src="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/thumb/004.jpg" alt="Image 004" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/full/005.jpg" rel="external"><img src="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/thumb/005.jpg" alt="Image 005" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/full/006.jpg" rel="external"><img src="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/thumb/006.jpg" alt="Image 006" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/full/007.jpg" rel="external"><img src="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/thumb/007.jpg" alt="Image 007" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/full/008.jpg" rel="external"><img src="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/thumb/008.jpg" alt="Image 008" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/full/009.jpg" rel="external"><img src="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/thumb/009.jpg" alt="Image 009" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){   
    var myPhotoSwipe = $(".gallery li a").photoSwipe({
        jQueryMobile: true,
        loop: false,
        enableMouseWheel: false,
        enableKeyboard: false
    });

    myPhotoSwipe.show(0);      
});
```